# Modifying an existing glyph to create new glyph

Tags: symbols, customize

I'm interested in modifying the `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` glyphs. I'd like them to function as they currently do, but I want to reduce their height to a fraction of the original. For example, .25 of the original.

I assume there's a lot going on under the hood to have glyphs adjust to changing fonts, font weights, and font sizes. How can I modify this glyph in a manner that I 'hook into' all existing functionality?

I'm comfortable with editing any code or format, like SVG, and am willing to learn whatever is necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't there Unicode slots for these? I think it would be good to see an example of what you like to obtain.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a Unicode slot (unless you mean a code for a specific Unicode glyph/character). I'd like to have functionality identical to $ \lfloor x \rfloor$ , but with the two surrounding floor glyphs being shorter. If I could parameterize their height, I could play around with what would look good.

Comment: Yes, like that. Maybe `\llcorner` (U+0231E) and `\lrcorner` (U+0231F) will do? I do not know how to make them work as `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` in LaTeX. In ConTeXt, when I type `\lowermarked{x} = \lowermarked{\frac{1}{2}}` in math mode, I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qtFd.png).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did try this initially. That's when I noticed the discrepancy between how close the brackets are to the symbol. I'll try to use an example with the application I have in mind. $\lfloor \underset{20}{A} \rfloor$ versus $\llcorner \underset{20}{A} \lrcorner$. 

Since these 'under brackets' might become nested in the application I have in mind, I want them to 'hug' the symbol as much, at least, as the floor symbol does. But I would like them to be roughly the height of the low-corner symbols.

I am thinking that I should look into MetaFont, at this stage.